# Java + Android: передать инициализированную переменную в другую активность

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как передать инициализированную переменную в другую активность?

Если сделать это приведённым ниже способом, то будет ошибка с указаниями, что переменная x не должна быть инициализирована.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int AddItemAction;
    int AddItemDefaultAction;
    AddItemDefaultAction = 1;

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddToInbox:
            AddItemAction = AddItemDefaultAction;
            break;
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddTextInputToInbox:
            AddItemAction = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddPenInputToInbox:
            AddItemAction = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddPhotoToInbox:
            AddItemAction = 3;
            break;
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddVideoToInbox:
            AddItemAction = 4;
            break;
        case R.id.MainMenuItem_AddSoundRedToInbox:
            AddItemAction = 5;
            break;
    }

    Intent AddItemIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItem.class);
    AddItemIntent.putExtra("AddItemAction", AddItemAction);
    startActivity(AddItemIntent);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текст ошибки то приложите

Comment: да что вы говорите, прям так и пишет `переменная x не должна быть инициализирована`?

Comment: Добавил скриншот (в моём проекте другие имена переменных).

Comment: Ваша ошибка гласит, что переменная ADD_ITEM_ACTION может быть не проинициализирована, проверьте что вы инициализируете её во всех ветвях кода

Comment: @GurebuBokofu снова у вас фарш с именованием всего и вся, ну да ладно, сейчас не об этом...так и английский вам следовало бы подучить, где тут `не должна быть инициализирована`...покажите где ваша `ADD_ITEM_ACTION` объявляется и инициализируется(хотя по всем канонам, такое имя имеют константы!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша переменная `AddItemAction` изначально не проинициализирована, а в `switch'е` нет блока `default`.
Таким образом если `view.getId()` не является ни одной из перечисленных в `case`, ваша переменная так и останется не проинициализированной.
Проинициализируйте переменную в самом начале или в блоке `default`.